# Display Statistics? SQL View, Sql trigger, Cached Values

Tags: sql, database, triggers, view

I am working on a web app and would like to be able to display some computed statistics about different objects to the user.  Some good examples would be: The "Top Questions" page on this site - SO - which lists "Votes", "Answers", and "Views" or the "Comment" and "Like" counts for a list of posts on the Facebook News Feed.  Actually computed values like these are used all over the web and I am not sure the best way to implement them.

I will describe in greater detail a generic view of the problem.  I have a single parent table in my database (you can visualize it as a blog post).  This table has a one-to-many relationship with 5  other tables (visualize it as comments and likes etc.).  I need to display a list of ~20 parent table objects with the counts of each related child object (visualize it as a list of blog posts each displaying the total number of comments and total number of likes).  I can think of multiple ways to tackle the problem, but I am not sure which would be the FASTEST and most ACCURATE.

Here are a number of options I have come up with...

1. SQL Trigger - Create a trigger to increment and decrement a computed
   count column on the parent table as the child tables have inserts
   and deletes performed.  In not sure about performance tradeoffs
   running the trigger every time a small child object is created or
   deleted.  I am also unsure about potential concurrency issues
   (although in my current architecture each row in the db can only be
   added or deleted by the row creator).
2. SQL View - Just an easier way to query and will yield accurate
   results, but I am worried about the performance implications for
   this type of view.
3. SQL Indexed View  - An indexed view would be accurate and
   potentially faster, but as each child table has rows that can be
   added or removed, the view would constantly have to be recalculated.
4. Cached Changes - Some kind of interim in process solution that would
   cache changes to the child tables, computed net changes to the
   counts, and flush them to the db based on some parameter.  This
   could potentially be coupled with a process that checks for accuracy
   every so often.
5. Something awesome I haven't thought of yet :)  How does SO keep
   track of soooo many stats??

Using SQL Server2008R2

Please keep in mind that I am building something custom and it is not a blog/FB/SO, I am just using them as an example of a similar problem so suggesting to just use those sites is unhelpful ;) I would love to hear how this is accomplished in live web apps that handle a decent volume of requests.

THANKS in Advance

Comment: Stackoverflow does it depending on how important that value is.  For instance, if it is something that has great meaning and changes dynamically very quickly they have to hit the db.  Check this link and watch the video by Brent Ozar - http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/11/how-stackoverflow-scales-sql-server-video/ - it is a fantastic video.

Comment: Very interesting video. I bookmarked the site. I would still be very much interested in hearing other specific examples of of how others are handling these types of situations. Thanks :)